# Regex to invert search in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regular-language

I have a string

```
2012-02-19 00:11:12,128|DEBUG|Thread-1|@@@ Time taken is 18 ms
```

Below regex allows me to search for `18 ms`

```
\d\d\s[m][s]
```

What I want to do is search for string prior to `18 ms` in Notepad++ and then delete it. So that out of thousands rows I have, I can just extract out timings.

Also, I need regex mentioned above to work with timings which are in 3 digits as well as 2 digits. For example it should be able to search for `18 ms` as well as `999 ms`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I need regex mentioned above to work with timings which are in 3 digits as well as 2 digits.

```
.*?(?=\d{2,3}\sms\b)
```

Use the above regex and then replace the match with empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You may put your regex into a positive lookahead:

```
^.*(?=\d{2,3}\sms\s*$)
```

In case you have some text after `18 ms`, you need to use a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> `\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`

```
^.*(?=\d{2,3}\sms\b)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM8rR7/5)

`{2,3}` is a [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) that lets you match 2 or 3 preceding subpattern.

> There's an additional quantifier that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated. The syntax is `{min,max}`, where min is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and `max` is an integer equal to or greater than `min` indicating the maximum number of matches. If the comma is present but `max` is omitted, the maximum number of matches is infinite.

You can replace with empty string and `18 ms` will stay on the line.

**Note** you can use `\d+` to allow 1 or more digits to be matched (without restrictions on the digit number).

**Note 2**: if your number is the first of many on the line you need to use *lazy  matching*, i.e. use `.*?` instead of `.*` in the beginning of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

Find:

```
^.*(\d{2,}\s[m][s])$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Comment: Can we use capturing groups in Notepad++. I'm not sure if this answer is relevant

Comment: @Identity1, http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Groups

Comment: Find + Replace will replace the matching line with group 1 (timing part only)